# What does the orange color marker mean in Sublime text2?

Tags: sublimetext2

This is the screenshot of the orange color marker in Sublime text2.

[image: orange color marker in Sublime text2]

[image: orange color marker in Sublime text2]

Best regards.

Comment: I would argue that this should not be closed based on the fact that it does exactly what the off-topic reasoning suggests it should be "unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming"

Comment: The orange/yellow dot that appears seems to show up when you are missing a closing tag in HTML. That is one of the reasons, there are multiple. Could not give a better answer without seeing more code.

Comment: What plugins do you have installed? I would guess that that (along with the outlined box) is the result of a linter plugin.

Comment: Thank you. I disable the "Tag" package, and the outlined box disappear.

Answer (score 2):

@JcKelley is right, it's part of the [Tag package](https://github.com/SublimeText/Tag), and it is showing an unclosed tag.

You can turn off "live tag linting" which will make the orange dots go away in `Prefs > Package settings > Tag` like so:

```
"enable_live_tag_linting": false
```

If you choose to remove the Tag package entirely, make sure to close the tag before removing the package or the orange dot will remain in your document and not go away.